# How did Chris gain the power of Garzey's Wing?

Tags: garzeys-wing

[image]

As confusing a show is as **Garzey's Wing**, and with stuff coming from nowhere and never seem to get explained, how did Chris' mental self in the alternate fantasy world gain the ability of Garzey's Wing and how the Chris in the real world suddenly acquire the same magical power (in the real world)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garzey%27s_Wing),

> Garzey's Wing is infamous for having a minimally explained plot, so most ideas of the purpose must be extrapolated. The protagonist Chris is abruptly whisked away to a parallel world called Byston Well while his physical body remains in his home world. Chris' spiritual manifestation travels to a new world, where he is thrust into a rebellion. Chris is told that he has a mystical power called "Garzey's wing", which causes large wings made of light to come out of his ankles, allowing him to fly and run quickly.

The reason that he gains the magical ability in the real world that he had in the fantasy world seems to be because of this:

> Chris exists simultaneously in Byston Well and the real world, and the two can communicate to each other through a necklace they both wear. Real-world Chris feels the bruises and pain Byston Well Chris experiences while fighting soldiers, and training he does in the real world allow him to learn it in Byston Well.

All in all, a main thing seems to be that it was simply not entirely explained within the show, which may have been in part because it was only three 30-minute episodes long.